# How to convert (Num a) => a to Float in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to combine the following two functions into one polymorphic function in Haskell?

```
mutiplyByTwoI :: Int -> Float
mutiplyByTwoI x = fromIntegral x * 2.0

mutiplyByTwoF :: Float -> Float
mutiplyByTwoF x = x * 2.0
```

I tried `Num a`, but I couldn't find a way to convert `Num a` to Float.

```
mutiplyByTwo :: (Num a) => a -> Float
mutiplyByTwo = undefined
```

Comment: You can try `fromIntegral` but it adds an additional constraint of `Integral`

Comment: @pdexter But Float is not an instance of Integral.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? The topic says "How to convert (Num a) => a to Float" but your question asks how to write a generic function to multiply a Num a by 2. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson `(*2) :: Num a => a -> a` can be `Int -> Int` or `Float -> Float`. But it can't be `Int -> Float`.

Comment: You should explain why you need the exact signature `multiplyBy2 :: Num a => a -> Float` , and perhaps we can show you how to organize your code differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
byTwo :: Real a => a -> Float
byTwo x = 2 * realToFrac x
```

which can be specialized to both types you request, `Int -> Float` and `Float -> Float`.

Answer (score 9):

Not every instance of `Num` has a sensible conversion to `Float`. For a simple (ha ha) example consider complex numbers:

```
-- represented in rectangular coordinates
data Complex = Complex { real :: Float, imaginary :: Float } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

instance Num Complex where
    Complex u v + Complex x y = Complex (u + x) (v + y)
    Complex u v * Complex x y = Complex (u * x - v * y) (v * x + u * y)
    negate (Complex u v) = Complex (negate u) (negate v)
    -- etc
```

Clearly there is no way to convert a `Complex` to a `Float` without throwing away information: `Float`s live on (a subset of) the real line whereas complex numbers live on the complex plane. There is no function `toFloat :: Num a => a -> Float` that works for all instances of `Num`.

Comment: `Complex` are not good `Num`s because every `Num` is supposed to have a `signum` (whether this is a good or bad thing I won't argue here ;)

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand why there is no `toFloat :: Num a => a -> Float`.

Comment: @nm The [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:signum) say nothing more restrictive than _The functions `abs` and `signum` should satisfy the law `abs x * signum x == x`_. There's a sensible implementation of this law for complex numbers: `abs (A e^iφ) = A` and `signum (A e^iφ) = e^iφ`. I omitted it from my answer because I couldn't be bothered to do the trig to convert from rectangular to polar.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Exactly. The only problem with the complex instance is that due to signum being more comple it might have rounding errors.

Comment: Yeah, saw that. So the signum is just the argument. This is stretching the definition IMHO.

Comment: @n.m. well, `Num` isn't a very good typeclass. It is at best poorly named.